# How to only allow Kana characters input

Tags: php, html, laravel-blade

I am trying to make an input box that accepts only Kana characters. So I do it this way:

```
<label>
    <input type="text" name="family_name_kana" placeholder="セイ" pattern="/[^\wぁ-ゔァ-ヺー\x{4E00}-\x{9FAF}_\-]+/u" value="{{ old('family_name_kana', $user->family_name_kana) }}"/>
 </label>
```

But it has error saying:

> Pattern attribute value /[^\wぁ-ゔァ-ヺー\x{4E00}-\x{9FAF}*-]+/u is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //[^\wぁ-ゔァ-ヺー\x{4E00}-\x{9FAF}*-]+/u/: Invalid escape

How can I properly allow the user to input Kana characters only using the HTML5 pattern attribute?

Comment: what is `\x{4E00}-\x{9FAF}` for?

Comment: I usually use `/[^\wぁ-ゔァ-ヺー]+/u`